# How can I enable the "Mac-like" taskbar in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, user-interface

I recently got a laptop with Windows 7 installed, which is showing the normal taskbar at the bottom and one taskbar with a glass-like appearance (similar to one in either Mac or Ubuntu), that has the icons for accessing the internet, email, and Windows Media Player (WMP).

But it suddenly disappeared, and I don't even know what it is called.

How can I get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a link when searched for "Dell Dock", will give it a try and let you know.

http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vistawu/thread/1291bbbd-cd67-4902-8f84-760ba6495daf

This just working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Was it looking [like this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d6UVb15it6A)?

It's called a **dock**, and it does not come with Windows - you have to install it separately. It might be [RocketDock](http://rocketdock.com/), [ObjectDock](http://www.stardock.com/products/objectdock/), or something else.

Comment: yes.. it came default with my laptop.  If windows 7 not providing, then DELL might have provided it. Will check if I could find out in the Dell's programs

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you have your normal windows seven task bar at the bottom but there is also a dock on your screen somewhere?

Something like the Mac OS x dock or [Rocketdock](http://rocketdock.com/)?

Some new computers come within a dock built in, if you look through your all programs menu through the start menu then just have a look in there, if you cant remember what its called just have a look through your programs until it comes up.

Comment: Yes it is very much looks like dock.  But it automatically disappeared after 1 or 2 days. I tried looking in start menu, but found nothing.  
Will have another look nevertheless.

Comment: If your computer was from DELL. Did the dock look like this: http://www.delldock.com/

Comment: If it is then it should be located under All Programs -> Dell -> Dell Dock